# Column doesn't want to center. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, all my pages have the same model, but this one doesn't want to center !

Do you have any idea where the problem come from ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

class OnBoardingDataPage1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoardingDataPage1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OnBoardingDataPage1> createState() => _OnBoardingDataPage1State();
}

class _OnBoardingDataPage1State extends State<OnBoardingDataPage1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 5.h),
              Text(
                "MugiwarApp",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
              ),
              Image.asset(
                "assets/images/animation.gif",
                height: 125.0,
                width: 125.0,
              )
            ]),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because column's parent are not bounded, so it takes size from its children. So wrap your `column` with `SizedBox` and set its width to `double.infinity`:

```
SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        ....
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Center widget in your widgets tree.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

class OnBoardingDataPage1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoardingDataPage1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OnBoardingDataPage1> createState() => _OnBoardingDataPage1State();
}

class _OnBoardingDataPage1State extends State<OnBoardingDataPage1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        ///Here
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 5.h),
                Text(
                  "MugiwarApp",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/animation.gif",
                  height: 125.0,
                  width: 125.0,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```